# Meaning of "everything else remaining the same"

Tags: macroeconomics, comparative-statics

Suppose in an economy, there is a representative firm, the government and a representative household who all have their individual budget constraints. The household maximizes its utility function and the firms maximize their profits (albeit in a competitive environment). If $\overline{M}$ (exogenous variable) is the money holding the household starts with and I am asked to find the relation between $\overline{M}$ and $P$ (the price level, another exogenous variable) assuming that "everything else remains the same" (ceteris paribus), do I assume the exogenous variables remain unchanged or do I assume that the endogenous variables remain unchanged too despite the change in the initial money holding?

Comment: I'm pretty sure everything ( exogenous and endogenous ) is supposed to remain the same but economics is not my academic background so anyone is welcome to correct me. P.S :  your name relates to the question nicely but you changed pari to marry. That must be an inside joke !!!!